# How to auto generate id using MongoDB and Spring Data MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I need to auto generate the id on my documents for persist on database. But if i don't set the id it has an error that cannot be null. How could I generate the id for reduce the repeated code and make it simple?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Id
private ObjectId id;I found a solution that is,
```

must the type of the id be an `org.bson.types.ObjectId`, like above:

```
@ToString
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor(staticName = "of")
public class Guide {

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    @NonNull
    private String name;

}
```

The right place that are the solution is:

> @Id private ObjectId id;